# Solve this combination with a summation. Edited and maybe Solved

Tags: proof-verification, summation, combinations

I have been quite stuck on this problem and with the help of others, I may have solved it. This is what I have to prove. 
    $$\binom{N}{n+1}=\sum^{N-1}_{k=n} \binom{k}{n}.$$

So far I have this
$${N \choose {n+1}}={{N-1}\choose{n+1}}+{{N-1}\choose n}.$$ by Pascals triangle. If I repeat this idea, I believe I end up with:
$$={{N-x}\choose{n+1}}+{{N-x}\choose{n}}...+{{{N-1}\choose n}}$$For some $x$ such that $x=n+1$. But lets go one further. 
$$={{N-x-1}\choose{n+1}}+{{N-x-1}\choose{n}}...+{{{N-1}\choose n}}.$$
But this reduces to $${{n}\choose{n+1}}+{{n}\choose{n}}...+{{{N-1}\choose n}}.$$ However $${{n}\choose{n+1}}=0$$. Therefore we are just left with: $\sum^{N-1}_{k=n} \binom{k}{n}.$ as desired.

Comment: Hint: Use Pascal's Rule.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218470/sum-of-combinations-with-varying-n/1218487#1218487

Comment: @PrasunBiswas edited with your idea. Maybe that will spark something.

Answer (score 0):

Prove by induction that, if $\,r\le N-n-2$: 
$$\binom N{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{r}\binom {N-1-i}n +\binom{N-1-r}{n+1}$$
Indeed, for $r=0$, it is Pascal's formula. If $r<N-n-2$, use again the formula in the last term:
\begin{align*} 
\binom N{n+1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{r}\binom {N-1-i}n +\binom{N-1-r-1}{n}+\binom{N-1-r-1}{n+1}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{r+1}\binom {N-1-i}n + \binom{N-1-r-1}{n+1}
\end{align*}

Now setting $r$ to the maximum value $N-n-2$, you get:
\begin{align*} 
\binom N{n+1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-n-2}\binom {N-1-i}n +\binom{n+1}{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-n-2}\binom {N-1-i}n +\binom nn=\sum_{i=0}^{N-n-1}\binom {N-i}n 
\end{align*}

Then set $k=N-1-i\,$ to get the formula.