# Find the Number of non decreasing Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

We know the No. of Non decreasing Sequence of `length N is (9+N)CN` How can we find the number of decreasing Sequence in a `Range [a,b]` of length 1 to N;

Comment: non-decreasing sequences

Comment: This question is from an ongoing competition see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1218435/18880 of which it is a duplicate. Competition is at http://www.codechef.com/APRIL15/problems/CSEQ

Answer (score 0):

First of all the number of non decreasing sequences of $[a,b]$ of lenght $M$ such that $M\in N$ equals to the number of non decreasing sequences of lenght $M$ with range $[1,a-b+1]$ (to see it you can transform every sequence in the first interval to a sequence in the second interval by subtracting $a-1$ from it).

Now if we take $N=a-b+1$ the question becaomes: what is the number of decreasing sequences of length $M$ in the range $[1,N]$ and the answer is:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{M}{N \choose r}{M-1 \choose r-1}$$

Comment: This question is asked again and again. I think we should encourage the people to search for it themselves (or even better, to enable them to do it themselves). You should not give a complete answer.

Comment: Did I need to delete my answer!

Comment: I did not find any completely duplicate question, But I reduced the problem to a question which is already in this site and the reduction is very simple I don't know what to do here!

Comment: Yes you caught me, but this question was asked more the $10$ times and always I made it duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218470/sum-of-combinations-with-varying-n) or I linked it to this one, and this is the first time I gave a "second" answer  for the same question (you can see the linked questions to the given post) and if you consult my profile you will never find two answers for the same question ever!!